# ANTLR - How to extact units from a dimension

Tags: c++, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 and the CSS grammar from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/css3. The grammar defines the following ( pared down a little for brevity )

```
dimension
    : ( Plus | Minus )? Dimension
    ;

fragment FontRelative
    : Number E M
    | Number E X
    | Number C H
    | Number R E M
    ;

fragment AbsLength
    : Number P X
    | Number C M
    | Number M M
    | Number I N
    | Number P T
    | Number P C
    | Number Q
    ;
fragment Angle
    : Number D E G
    | Number R A D
    | Number G R A D
    | Number T U R N
    ;
fragment Length
    : AbsLength
    | FontRelative
    ;
Dimension
    : Length
    | Angle
    ;
```

The matching works fine but I don't see an obvious way to extract the units. The parser creates a `DimensionContext` which has 3 `TerminalNode` members - `Dimension`, `Plus` and `Minus`. I'd like to be able to extract the unit during parse without having to do additional string parsing.

I know that one issue that the Length and Angle are fragments. I changed the grammar not use fragments

```
Unit
    : 'em'
    | 'ex'
    | 'ch'
    | 'rem'
    | 'vw'
    | 'vh'
    | 'vmin'
    | 'vmax'
    | 'px'
    | 'cm'
    | 'mm'
    | 'in'
    | 'pt'
    | 'q'
    | 'deg'
    | 'rad'
    | 'grad'
    | 'turn'
    | 'ms'
    | 's'
    | 'hz'
    | 'khz'
    ;
    
Dimension : Number Unit;
```

And things still parse but I don't get any more context about what the units are - the `Dimension` is still a single `TerminalNode`. Is there a way to deal with this without having to pull apart the full token string?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do as little as possible in the lexer:

```
NUMBER
    : Dash? Dot Digit+ { atNumber(); }
    | Dash? Digit+ ( Dot Digit* )? { atNumber(); }
    ;

UNIT
    : { aftNumber() }? 
        ( 'px'  | 'cm'  | 'mm'   | 'in'
        | 'pt'  | 'pc'  | 'em'   | 'ex'
        | 'deg' | 'rad' | 'grad' | '%'
        | 'ms'  | 's'   | 'hz'   | 'khz' 
        )
    ;
```

The trick is to produce the `NUMBER` and `UNIT` as separate tokens, yet limited to the required ordering. The actions in the `NUMBER` rule just set a flag and the `UNIT` predicate ensures that a `UNIT` can only follow a `NUMBER`:

```
protected void atNumber() {
    _number = true;
}

protected boolean aftNumber() {
    if (_number && Character.isWhitespace(_input.LA(1))) return false;
    if (!_number) return false;
    _number = false;
    return true;
}
```

The parser rule is trivial, but preserves the detail required:

```
number
    : NUMBER UNIT?
    ;
```

Use a tree-walk, parse the `NUMBER` to a Double and an enum (or equivalent) to provide the semantic `UNIT` characterization:

```
public enum Unit {

    CM("cm", true, true),   // 1cm = 96px/2.54
    MM("mm", true, true),   
    IN("in", true, true),   // 1in = 2.54cm = 96px
    PX("px", true, true),   // 1px = 1/96th
    PT("pt", true, true),   // 1pt = 1/72th
    EM("em", false, true),   // element font size
    REM("rem", false, true), // root element font size
    EX("ex", true, true),   // element font x-height
    CAP("cap", true, true), // element font nominal capital letters height
    PER("%", false, true),
    DEG("deg", true, false),
    RAD("rad", true, false),
    GRAD("grad", true, false),
    MS("ms", true, false),
    S("s", true, false),
    HZ("hz", true, false),
    KHZ("khz", true, false),
    NONE(Strings.EMPTY, true, false), // 'no unit specified'
    INVALID(Strings.UNKNOWN, true, false);

    public final String symbol;
    public final boolean abs;
    public final boolean len;

    private Unit(String symbol, boolean abs, boolean len) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.abs = abs;
        this.len = len;
    }

    public boolean isAbsolute() { return abs; }
    public boolean isLengthUnit() { return len; }

    // call from the visitor to resolve from `UNIT` to Unit
    public static Unit find(TerminalNode node) {
        if (node == null) return NONE;
        for (Unit unit : values()) {
            if (unit.symbol.equalsIgnoreCase(node.getText())) return unit;
        }
        return INVALID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not having much luck with your suggestions. Any number that either doesn't have a unit or uses % seems to work ok but if I use any string based unit they end up being UnknownTerms. Here's the grammar I was using - https://pastebin.com/hMSnxEg7. I am using a c++ parser but I think I translated the atNumber and aftNumber functions properly. In the working case ( no unit or % ) I get the atNumber callback but for the other cases atNumber is never called.

Comment: Cannot just drop it in and expect it to work. You will need to go through and adapt every reference to `Number` to work through the new `number` rule. (While your starting grammar is canonical, it is going to require a significant refactoring to produce a parse tree that is easy to work with -- at least that was my experience.)